# Open Design and expandability in GO

Tags: go, struct, interface, abstraction

I try to implement some kind of open design paradigm with expandability in go, but wonder what would be the gopher way of doing this.

For example I have a vehicle package. Depending on what implementations are available, I want to create an array of all possible vehicles. In this example if just bike is available I want an array [bike] if there is another car implementation I want to have [bike,car]

I don't really get how to do this in go. I thought for an interface in the vehicle package, but I don't really get how to create the array depending on which package is available. And this should be open design, so that if somebody decides to write another vehicle, a truck i.e. it would automatically work upstream.

So this is some example code for the explained issue:
If it's not necessary, that they are devided into packages, they could also be in the same package (vehicles)

vehicle.go

```
package vehicle

type vehicle interface {
    drive() string
}
```

bike.go

```
package bike

type bike struct {
    name string
}

func (b *bike) drive() string {
    return "drive bike drive"
}

func NewVehicle() bike {
    return &bike{
        name: "bike",
    }
}
```

car.go

```
package car

type carstruct {
    name string
}

func (b *car) drive() string {
    return "drive cardrive"
}

func NewVehicle() car{
    return &car{
        name: "car",
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you may want to look how standard lib `image` and `image/jpeg` and `image/png" work together. Sorry I am on mobile, if you wish, I can elaborate later.

Comment: not exactly, as I later want to range over the slice of vehicles. in this example I would want to let all vehicles drive. image and image/jpeg work the way, that I import image/jpeg explicitly. In my case the the developer shouldn't even know what vehicle implementaions are there he should just call vehicles and work with them genericaly

Comment: Are you looking for [plugins](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Depending on what implementations are available"? The implementations must be supplied by the programmer, and must conform to some api. Where else are they coming from?

Comment: @JimB in a real world scenario, their would be hardware drivers, and you don't know what drivers area available. so you just want to use something like hardware.start() but you don't know which driver for which hardware will execute the start() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the design of `image` and `database/sql` and how they co-operate with other libs more idomatic, but if you really need to implent this kind of design, I have come up with some thing hack-y.

The trick is, golang can do function calls during declaration of global vars and that happens before calling any of `init`. So we can do the register job during that.

```
//vehicle.go
import (
    "fmt"
)

var _ = register("3",4)

type constructor func() *Vehicle

var reg = make(map[string]consturctor)

func register(name string, cons) bool {
    _,ok:=reg[name]
    if ok {
        return false
    }
    reg[name] = cons
    return true
}

var chosen string

func init() {
    //turn that map into a slice if you want
    //Chose one "implentation" from the slice/map if you wish
    for chosen = range reg {
        break // Take the first, it is dirty, I know.
    }
    if Chosen=="" {
        panic("No Implentation!")
    }
}

func NewVehicle() *Vehicle {
    return reg[chosen]() 
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

//car.go

var carsucc = register("car",constructor(NewCar))

func init() {
    if !carsucc {
        panic("car: multiple implentation!")
    }
    //off course you can fail silently
}

func NewCar() Vehicle {
    return &Car{}
}
```

Comment: as you say, the design of image/jpeg is more idiomatic. This approach doesn't fit my needs, no? I want the developer just (in an image example) say: I want a new image, create it with whatever format you have. This is not as image/jpeg works in my understanding. image/jpeg works more like give me a new jpeg image. right?

Comment: @Florian You made your point and I am not going to argue against it. Though If I am a developer using the lib, I would like myself being the one control the components. But this might be personal, I can't say for every scenero. And does the code beneath that comment satisfy your requirement?

Comment: yes it does. I totaly agree with you. But in this case of course I'm not really coding cars, it's about hardware drivers, and the system should automatically use the driver that fits for the hardware. So the developer himself has no idea which driver is used in production later.

Comment: I only have one time programing with hardware and it was like 5 years ago so I really did not take hardware into consideration. It seems makes perfect sense. I will keep looking if there are more idomatic way of doint this. I will let you know If I find one.